# Why are answers deleted because the question was made long gone?

Tags: support, allowed-answers

I was saying the right answers and not duplicating and I got upvotes.But my answers are deleted because the question was asked long ago why is that?

Answer (score 4):

First off, welcome to Arqade!

The answers were not deleted because the questions themselves were old. There are many occasions where old questions have new answers because either the previous answer was incorrect, or new information had been discovered.

Below are some cases I found that is warranting your question, and comments from other users:

> I don't know why this is an answer instead of an edit, as it doesn't really seem to add anything meaningful on its own
>
> <sub>[Link to answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/384594/124566)</sub>

and

> This was already mentioned more than three years ago. Please read existing answers carefully before adding your own
>
> <sub>[Link to answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/384658/124566)</sub>

In the first scenario, the answer didn't make much sense as a stand-alone answer. Based on the user's comment, editing the existing answer would have been the better approach. Due to your reputation, it would have gone into the queue for the community to review, and either approve or reject the edit.

In the second scenario, you were essentially repeating what had already been said. Posting another answer (whether it be 1 day, 1 year, or 5 years after) that contains essentially the same information does not provide much benefit to the question or the community.